# Netlogo: How do I move each turtle to a specfied location and stay for a set amount of time using 'matrix'?

Tags: netlogo

I want to move a set of turtles to specific locations, determined by data on each turtle, and have them stay at each location for a set amount of time, before moving to the next location. I have coded in the locations as a turtle and now have a matrix of locations and times for each turtle. However, I end up with an error that my trajectory and movement patterns are not a matrix. My code is below

Code to set-up the matrix of locations and time(small example of data):

```
    let herd1 matrix:from-row-list [[11 12 13 14 15] [30 23 2 14 10]]
  let herd2 matrix:from-row-list [[13 12 14 11 15] [20 12 3 35 6]]
  set movement-patterns (list herd1 herd2)
```

Code to set-up these turtles:

```
to setup-mobile-herds
  ask mobile-herds [die]
  create-mobile-herds (initial-mobile-herds) [   ;
    set shape "cow"
    set size 0.9
    set color yellow

    set sus 30
    set inf 0
    set rec 0


    set trajectory movement-patterns 


    foreach n-values movement-patterns [ ?1 -> ?1 ] [ ?1 ->
      ask item ?1 movement-patterns [
        set mobile-S who
      ]
    ]


    move-to (matrix:get trajectory 0 0)   ;I'm getting an error here that says this is not a matrix
    set time-cap (matrix:get trajectory 1 0)
    set transmission-rate mobile-transmission-rate
  ]

 end
```

I need each turtle to be assigned to one row of data and use this information as the trajectory and time at each point. I have tried adding code to eat off each row but this does not work either. I get an error that item input expected a string but got a number 0 instead.

Code to remove a row as it is used:

```
set mobile-number count mobile-herds                                        ;provides number of herds
set mobile-index (mobile-number - (initial-mobile-herds - 1))               
set trajectory item mobile-index movement-patterns
```

I want to figure out what I'm missing with the matrix primitives?

Comment: Could you please clarify how your input data relates to location and time? For example, your example data `[[11 12 13 14 15] [30 23 2 14 10]]` - is that go to location 11 and stay for 30 ticks, then go to location 12 for 23 ticks etc?

Comment: @JenB Yes, that is how the input data is set-up. I have locations first and for each location there is an associated length of time the turtle remains there, before moving to the next location.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that your variable trajectory is a list, not a matrix. Ignoring all the moving and duration, which is irrelevant to the error, here is a cut down version of your code with some output added:

```
extensions [matrix]

globals [ trajectory ]

to testme
  let herd1 matrix:from-row-list [[11 12 13 14 15] [30 23 2 14 10]]
  let herd2 matrix:from-row-list [[13 12 14 11 15] [20 12 3 35 6]]
  let movement-patterns (list herd1 herd2)
  set trajectory movement-patterns
  show trajectory
  show item 0 trajectory
  show matrix:get (item 0 trajectory) 0 0
end
```

You can see that trajectory is a list of matrices, not a matrix. You can then get an individual matrix using the list primitive `item` and access that individual matrix with `matrix:get`.

However, I don't know whether that's actually your problem because you stated that this is example data. Is your real data set up the same way as your example data?

Comment: The rest of my data is set up the same way but now I think I have issues with moving the herd turtles to each of the locations. I'm getting an error that `item` expected an agent but got 11, which is the first location. I will work on figuring out `move-to` now.

Comment: `item` doesn't expect an agent, but `move-to` does. I strongly suggest you code more incrementally, get the right data into the right place, then sort out moving, then sort out staying for the right time. At the moment, it appears that problems with one aspect are interfering with solving other problems.